# is there any way to break the loop in drools while iterating child condition

Tags: drools

I have a customer fact and it has many stocks fact.

I am looking  to break the item loop after ist matching.

```
List<Stocks> stocks = new ArrayList<Stocks>();
   stocks.add(new Stocks("Apple", 10, 100));
   stocks.add(new Stocks("Google", 35, 28));

   Customer customer = new Customer();
   customer.setStocks(stocks);
   customer.setCustId("ABC123");


   List<Stocks> stocks2 = new ArrayList<Stocks>();
   stocks2.add(new Stocks("Apple", 10, 100));
   stocks2.add(new Stocks("Google", 35, 28));
   stocks2.add(new Stocks("salesforce", 160, 40));

   Customer customer2 = new Customer();
   customer2.setStocks(stocks2);
   customer2.setCustId("ABC456");

   ksession.insert(customer);
   ksession.insert(customer2);
   ksession.fireAllRules();
```

Here is my drl file

```
rule "RS0Test"
 when
     $c : Customer()
      $items : List( size > 1 )  from collect
      (Stocks(quantity>1) from $c.stocks )

 then
       System.out.println("Customer : " + $c.getCustId() );

end
```

result/output:

```
 Customer : ABC456
 Customer : ABC123
```

Please suggest.

Appreciate your help.

I am thinking of creating a local variable count and modify the child fact stock by incrementing the value or use the break logic in the first instance.

Comment: I can't see any loops in your code, so I have no idea how you might break out of one...

Comment: Thanks for the reply,i want to break from collect  if stock.item="Apple"

Comment: But collect isn't a loop...

Comment: You should describe your problem in terms of "customer" and "stock", **not** in terms of **loop**, **variable**.

Comment: Your rule says: "For each customer that has 2 or more Stocks items where the quantity is 2 or more: print the customer id." Please describe what you want in this way.